Methods to analyze biomarker data to detect pathologies (and co-pathologies)
I'm trying to do analysis to determine what biomarkers are able to detect specific pathologies. I am looking at 4 separate pathologies, however the problem is they often co-occur with eachother. So if I were to split people into groups, instead of getting 4 group, I end up 12 different groups. Each group ranges from having 1-3 pathologies and the sample size becomes quite small (ranging from 2-15 per group). This has made standard group-wise analysis not very feasible, but I am unsure how to otherwise tease apart how these categorical variables are contributing to biomarker levels and how to determine the effects of having multiple pathologies.
The primary question of this research is just about finding biomarkers to detect the unique pathologies. But the secondary, and potentially more interesting question, is to determine if someone has pathology #1 can you also use biomarkers to detect the co-pathology #2. If anyone has any advice or resources on how to start tackling this problem it would be greatly appreciated!

Hi @jcoop, welcome to CV. Could you put some examples of what a "pathology" looks like in terms of data? I think that it would be helpful for people (like me) who don't work in biology, to understand the issue :)
